# Empty operation-functions when using the Composite Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, composite

I'm trying to write a game using the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

 
If i understand this right, every component has a operation-function that will be called in every frame. 
Every composite(entity) has a operation-function, that will call the operation-functions of it's components.

 
My problem is, that some components don't need a operation-function, because they only store information; i.e a position-component. 

Is it ok, to solve this by just leaving the functions empty? If not, is there a better way?

**EDIT :** I found out, that it doesn't matter. The Compiler ignores empty function calls if optimization is turned on. So it's maybe not as nice, but just as fast.

Comment: Generally, I'd say that's fine. That's called a *no-op* (no-operation). But to be sure, you'd have to provide more info. What's the composite and what's the leaf? What their responsibility? What does this operation-function do?

Comment: I'm curious about this hierarchy you are trying to put into a composite. You must remember that composite relates to objects of the same family that shoul have the same behaviour no matter if it's a leaf or a composite...